# Spring: Field in --- required a bean of type

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, godaddy-api

Hello everyone and indeed I have the following problem. I am trying to connect to a GoDaddy DB with my Spring Boot application.

Here I encounter the following problem:

`Field driverService in com.example.accounting.controller.ClientController required a bean of type 'com.example.accounting.service.DriverService' that could not be found.`

My folder structure looks like this:

```
Nova_2_Test-master
    ├───.mvn
    │   └───wrapper
    ├───.vscode
    ├───src
    │   ├───main
    │   │   ├───java
    │   │   │   └───com
    │   │   │       └───example
    │   │   │           └───accounting
    │   │   │               ├───controller
    │   │   │               ├───model
    │   │   │               ├───repo
    │   │   │               └───service
    │   │   └───resources
    │   └───test
    │       └───java
    │           └───com
    │               └───example
    │                   └───accounting
    └───target
        ├───classes
        │   └───com
        │       └───example
        │               ├───controller
        │               ├───model
        │               ├───repo
        │               └───service
        ├───generated-sources
        │   └───annotations
        ├───generated-test-sources
        │   └───test-annotations
        └───test-classes
            └───com
                └───example
                    └───accounting
```

ClientController

```
package com.example.accounting.controller;



import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.accounting.model.Driver;
import com.example.accounting.service.DriverService;
//import com.example.accounting.service.DriverServiceImplementation;

@RestController
public class ClientController {
    @Autowired
    private DriverService driverService;
    


    @GetMapping("/")
    public String helloworld(){
        return "Hello World!";
    }

    // Rest API Crud - Create Driver - POST
    // Read Driver - GET
    // Delete Driver - DELETE
    // Update Driver - PUT

    //create Driver
    @PostMapping("/add")
    public Driver createDriver(@RequestBody Driver driver){
        Driver driver1 = driverService.createDriver(driver);
        return driver1;
    }

    // Read Drivers
    @GetMapping("/drivers")
    public List<Driver> getDrivers(){
        return driverService.getDrivers();
    }
    
    // Update Drivers By DL_Number
    @PutMapping("/update/{DL_Number}")
    public Driver updateDriverById(@RequestBody Driver driver, @PathVariable("DL_Number") String DL_Number) {
        return driverService.updateDriver(driver, DL_Number);
    }

    // Delete Driver By DL_Number
    @DeleteMapping("/delete/{DL_Number}")
    public String deleteDriver(@PathVariable("DL_Number") String DL_Number) {
        driverService.deleteDriver(DL_Number);
        return "Driver Deleted Successfully..";
    }

    // Get Driver By DL_Number
    @GetMapping("/driver/{DL_Number}")
    public Driver getDriverById(@PathVariable("DL_Number") String DL_Number) {
        return driverService.getDriverById(DL_Number);
    }

}
```

DriverService

```
package com.example.accounting.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.accounting.model.Driver;

@Service

public interface DriverService {
    // create driver
    public Driver createDriver(Driver driver);

    // read drivers
    public List<Driver> getDrivers();

    // read driver by DL_Number
    public Driver getDriverById(String DL_Number);

    // delete driver by DL_Number
    public void deleteDriver(String DL_Number);

    // update driver by DL_Number
    public Driver updateDriver(Driver driver, String DL_NumbeString);
}
```

DriverServiceImplementation

```
package com.example.accounting.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;


import com.example.accounting.model.Driver;
import com.example.accounting.repo.DriverRepo;



public class DriverServiceImplementation implements DriverService{
    
@Autowired
private DriverRepo driverRepo;

    @Override
    public Driver createDriver(Driver driver) {
        return driverRepo.save(driver);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Driver> getDrivers() {
        return (List<Driver>) driverRepo.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Driver getDriverById(String DL_Number) {
        return driverRepo.findById(DL_Number).get();
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteDriver(String DL_Number) {
        driverRepo.deleteById(DL_Number);
    }

    @Override
    public Driver updateDriver(Driver driver, String DL_Number) {
        Driver driver1 = driverRepo.findById(DL_Number).get();
        driver1.setCell(driver.getCell());
        driver1.setCompanyName(driver.getCompanyName());
        driver1.setDOB(driver.getDOB());
        driver1.setDriving_Under(driver.getDriving_Under());
        driver1.setEmail(driver.getEmail());
        driver1.setFirstname(driver.getFirstname());
        driver1.setLastname(driver.getLastname());
        driver1.setPrepass(driver.getPrepass());
        driver1.setDL_State(driver.getDL_State());
        driver1.setStatus(driver.getStatus());
        return driverRepo.save(driver1);
    }
    

}
```

I would be very grateful if you could help me. I am new to programming and have to do this for university and am pretty hopeless right now.

I tried to switch to the class DriverServiceImplementation within the class ClientControler instead of using the interface Driver Service. Only gives more errors

Comment: Do you have a concrete implementation of `DriverService`?

Comment: And it’s the concrete class implementing DriverService that should be annotated @Service.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `@Service` annotation from the `DriverService` interface and add that into the `DriverServiceImplementation` class.